# Accessing balloon tips from VBA

Tags: vba, balloon, popup-balloons

How do you access balloon tips in the task tray area using VBA? I'm looking to find some simple methods to display and possibly even interact with the user.

I am using Windows XP and MS Access 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the task tray, but one way would be to use the office assistant.

See [Use the Office Assistant as an Alternative to Displaying and Retrieving User Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163981(office.10).aspx#odc_offtips_topic10)

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, but apparently the Office Assistant is deprecated (ie. not really functional) in Office 2007 and later.  If you're only using 2003 it might be OK.